# How to remove Phone Number from user account in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm guessing you have to do something with re authing to remove the phone number because at the moment I am trying to do this:

`const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;`

`user.updateProfile({phoneNumber: null}).then(() => { alert('success') }).catch(err => {alert(err)})`

this is not working, but I am getting the success block

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove a phone number account from a user, simply [unlink](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#unlink) it:

`firebase.auth().currentUser.unlink(firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID);`

Comment: How do we get the Provider id?

Comment: What do you mean? It is a constant: `firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID`

Comment: I forgot to delete the comment haha, I found this out 2 minutes after, I apologize. Very new to firebase

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is looking for an answer to this question from an Admin SDK perspective, you just set the phoneNumber field on the UserRecord to null.

`admin.auth().updateUser( user.uid, { phoneNumber: null } )`

Comment: This method requires Cloud Functions which is expensive :)

Comment: My authentication starts with phoneNumber, I'm sure others have/will too, so I'll explain what I had to do to nullify email after verifying it for banking and such (unofficial firebase-php seems to do the same).  Setting email: var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; user.updateEmail(this.state.newEmail).then(() => {user.sendEmailVerification().then(()=>{});}). Clearing email (in firebase functions): admin.auth().deleteUser(userId).then(() => {admin.auth().createUser({uid: userId,phoneNumber: phone}).then(() => {})}).  Try to make it tiresome so users don't abuse it

Comment: This is the documentation where this is explained https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users):

> You can update a user's basic profile information—the user's display
>   name and profile photo URL—with the updateProfile method.

This means you can only update the user's display name and profile photo. There's also the `updateEmail` method which can be used to update the user's email. But there's no way to update the phone.

Comment: There is an `updatePhoneNumber` method which is what I used to add the phone number to the account, but it takes a `phoneCredential` which only takes a valid number I believe so Im not sure how to pass a null value through this.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're looking to update this single phone number on your database, you can use the [Firebase Auth CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) and export your data to a JSON file, remove the number and import it back.

Comment: Im not sure how to implement that on a web application

Comment: You don't implement it in your application. You need to install the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/) on your computer and use the commands found in the link I provided.

Comment: This needs to be in an application as it is part of it

Comment: Just found the [docs for the updatePhoneNumber](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updatePhoneNumber) that you mentioned earlier. From what I see there, this method is used when the user wants to change the number he used to signIn. I don't think this will remove the phoneNumber.

Comment: Yeah that is what Im seeing because you need to pass a valid phone number through in order to do this.