# How to reauthenticate user who signed in with phone number in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I need to add the option for users to delete their accounts from within the app but I just don´t know how to do it, I found some information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) where it explains that we need to ask the user to sign in again otherwise we´ll get an error, but it only explains how to reauthenticate the user when this signed in using an email address and it does not say anything about when a phone number was used instead.

Comment: Have you tried this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48407214/9346054

Comment: That only removes the phone number from the user account but the account still exists, I´m trying to delete the account completely.

Comment: This is covered in the Getting Started Guide. [Delete a User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#delete_a_user). That's Swift but there are similar calls for other platforms. Can you elaborate on what the issue is?

Comment: If you take a look at the link I put on the question you'll see that I found the started guide for android, it explains how to delete a user's account but there's something that says "Important: To delete a user, the user must have signed in recently. See Re-authenticate a user." and that's precisely what I don't know how to do (re-authenticate the user) when he signed in using a phone number.

Comment: Hmm. From the docs: *The example below shows email and password credentials but there are multiple possible providers, such as GoogleAuthProvider or FacebookAuthProvider.* or PhoneAuthProvider. No? It seems that auth type also has a [.getCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#create-a-phoneauthcredential-object) function. Have you tried some code? If so, can you share it and let us know what part you're stuck on?